# Internal или Public? Что лучше использовать?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я только решил задуматься о безопасности своей игры написанной на Unity.
Так во-о-от...

По-сути Internal доступен из любого места моей программы также, как и public. Так что же лучше?
Я везде могу вместо public поставить internal и ничего не изменится, всё также хорошо, как и раньше, будет работать.

Как я понял, public доступен даже тогда, когда игра сбилдилась, и допустим любые другие программы (к примеру читы) смогут читать и изменять любые public, не внедряясь в код и не меняя его, а internal читать и менять не смогут, если читы не внедряются в код...

В общем я запутался, прошу помочь мне разобраться в разнице между public и internal...

Comment: Я заметил, что internal не видно в инспекторе, в отличие от public, но это можно решить с помощью [SerializeField]

Comment: Если пользуешься папкой `Editor` для написания кастомного инспектора, то в решении `Assembly-CSharp-Editor` не увидеть класса с методом доступа `internal`, только в основном `Assembly-CSharp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чаще это нужно для библиотек, чтобы запретить использовать переменные вашей библиотеке в других проектах. 
Это мало как защищает ваше приложение, только делает его более безопасным для других разработчиков. 
Для защиты приложений следует задуматься над использованием sealed классов, т.к в ином случае любой человек может взять dll вашего приложения и модифицировать классы под себя. 
Так например, в terraria можно было модифицировать главный класс игры и изменять часть методов. Как например, можно было запускать игру без steam и рисовать информацию об других игроках на экране.

Comment: До тех пор, пока ты не подписываешь код и/или не химичишь с хэшами зависимостей, можно взять твою dll и просто заменить на свою.

Answer (score 3):

Модификаторы доступа никак не влияют на безопасность приложения (по крайней мере прямо, то как вы описали в вопросе). Т.е. даже `private` поля можно поменять без особых проблем, у кого будет желание - он всегда сможет это сделать.

Модификаторы доступу в основном предназначено для реализации одного из принципов ООП: **инкапсуляция**. Если посмотреть в Wiki, что это такое, что там есть такое описание:

> Инкапсуля́ция (лат. in capsula; от capsula «коробочка») — размещение в оболочке, изоляция, закрытие чего-либо инородного с целью исключения влияния на окружающее. Например, поместить радиоактивные отходы в капсулу, закрыть кожухом механизм, убрать мешающее в ящик или шкаф.

*Я специально использовал определение инкапсуляции не из программирования. Мне кажется оно более понятным для начинающих.*

И в программирование это также работает. Пометив поле как `public`, вы сразу же разрешаете любому коду как читать, так и писать в него, что может приводить к проблемам. От простой путаницы, т.к. непонятно кто и когда поменял значение поля, до того, что просто можно сломать код.

Предположим в вашей игре есть класс:

```cs
class Game
{
    public int score; // количество очков игрока
}

// ...

var game = new Game();
game.score = 1337;
```

Тут видно, что можно где угодно и как угодно можно повлиять на класс, что может привести к вышеописанным проблемам. Класс - это черный ящик, у которого должна быть одна ответственность (задача которую он решает) и всем кто "смотрит" на него извне, не должны знать как он внутри работает. У них есть только публичный контракт (методы и свойства), через которые он взаимодействует с ним.

Рассмотрим следующий пример:

```cs
class Game
{
    private void AddScore() => Score++;

    public void Move()
    {
        // какая-то логика
        if (something)
            AddScore();
    }

    public int Score { get; private set; }
}

// ...

var game = new Game();
game.Score = 1337; // тут будет ошибка, т.к. мы не можем вмещаться
```

У таком случае, когда кто-то пытается использовать такой код, то он может использовать метод `Move`, который, предположим, расчитывает логику игры и делает ход и на оставании состояния игры обновляет количество очков. Т.е. программист не пытается таким образом огранизовать безопасность всего преложения. Он просто сам себе помагает (создавая "закрытые" компоненты) и защищает (от воздействий из "внешней" среды).

Comment: В шарпе есть какие-то уровне доверия к коду и если он исполняется не с FullTrust, то никакого доступа к private из вне не выйдет. С другой стороны, я не знаю, может ли юнити работать без FullTrust. Ну и вообще, я никогда с этой темой не разбирался и только слышал, что теоретически так надо грузить код плагинов в программу.

Comment: @Qwertiy я не думаю, что .net полность следит за всей памятью и запрещает изменять её, я думаю, можно вмешаться в процесс и поменять значение переменной или переписать IL и убрать не нужные if и т.д., для защиты от этого есть другие вещи, но никак не модификаторы доступа.

Comment: Есть методы, помеченные как требующие некого уровня доверия. При попытке вызвать такой метод без соответствующего доверия будет исключение. Т. е. можно запретить рефлексию и unsafe-код. Память контролируется с любом случае - без этого не смог бы работать сборщик мусора.

Comment: @Qwertiy сборщик мусора ничего не знает о внешних модификациях, я говорил про такой случай, как раньше использовалось в ArtMoney, т.е. внешний процесс изменяет данные в игре, и GC тут точно никак не защищает это не его задача, возможно в новых ОС есть защита, но все равно для защиты от таких изменение используют различные античиты, Denuvo и т.д.

Comment: Ну внешний процесс может что угодно переписать, тут вопросы к нему. Я говорил именно из программы законным способом. Кстати, может быть сложно переписать конкретные данные, если сборщик мусора таскает объекты по памяти.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну да, но вы уже упомянули, что даже внутри, есть reflection. И все сводится к тому, что модификаторы доступа не для безопасности

Comment: Reflection работает только при достаточном доверии (подозреваю, что full trust).

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/8skskf63(v=vs.100)

Comment: @Qwertiy начиная с .NET Core уровни доверия кода не существуют.

Comment: @aepot, не знал. А почему?

Comment: @Qwertiy архитектурно так решили видимо в .NET. Что там в Mono, я кстати не знаю, здесь все-таки вопрос больше про Unity.

Answer (score 1):

По сути уровни доступа нужны только ради инкапсуляции и обратной совместимости при обновлениях библиотеки (как бинарной, так и в исходниках).

Если ты не делаешь библиотеку, которую будет использовать много людей, а тем более, если ты пишешь весь код сам, можешь при сомнениях между internal и public выбирать public (а вот при разработке библиотек рекомендуют делать наоборот).

Уровни доступа по умолчанию не влияют на безопасность, поскольку с помощью рефлексии можно их полностью игнорировать. На самом деле, игнорировать можно не всегда, но ситуации, когда код, обращающийся к чему-то работает не с FullTrust на мой взгляд, крайне редки.

Упомянутый в другом ответе sealed служит примерно той же цели - в первую очередь обратная совместимость если кого-то угораздит отнаследоваться от твоего класса. Ну и немного безопасности: унаследовавшийся получит доступ к protected и сможет что-то с ним делать, но в плане безопасности это оппять же играет роль только в случае выполнения с ограниченным уровнем доверия.